# How to access fragment elements via adapter?

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-activity

I have LoginActivity.class, that uses adapter on onCreate()

```
final LoginAdapter loginAdapter = new LoginAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), this, tabLayout.getTabCount());
    viewPager.setAdapter(loginAdapter);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
```

LoginAdapter.class

```
public class LoginAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

private Context context;
int totalTabs;

public LoginAdapter(@NonNull FragmentManager fm,Context context, int totalTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.context = context;
    this.totalTabs = totalTabs;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return totalTabs;
}

public Fragment getItem(int position){

    switch (position){
        case 0:
            LoginTabFragment loginTabFragment = new LoginTabFragment();
            return loginTabFragment;
        case 1:
            RegisterTabFragment registerTabFragment = new RegisterTabFragment();
            return registerTabFragment;
        default:
            return null;
    }}}
```

LoginTabFragment.class

```
public class LoginTabFragment extends Fragment {

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ViewGroup root = (ViewGroup) inflater.inflate(R.layout.login_tab_fragment, container, false);
    return root;
}}
```

LoginActivity need to get access to fields which are at login_tab_fragment.xml.

```java
userNameInput = findViewById(R.id.login_username_input);
passwordInput = findViewById(R.id.login_password_input);
loginBtn = findViewById(R.id.login_email_login_btn);
loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

    }
});
```

I get NPE:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Button.setOnClickListener(android.view.View$OnClickListener)' on a null object reference
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2778)
```

How do I get access to elements of LoginTabFragment in LoginActivity? Thank you.

Comment: I think your problem might be just that your button is not found when calling `loginBtn = findViewById(R.id.login_email_login_btn);` and is therefore `null`. Might be wrong though, this is merely from a quick glance.

Comment: he calling fragment views in activity

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define public method in your activity that you can call

1. Define this method in your activity

   ```
   public void responseFromFragment(View v){
   //do your things in activity
   }
   ```
2. Call method from Fragment

   ```
   loginBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
   @Override
   public void onClick(View v) {
   ((YourActivityClassName)getActivity()).responseFromFragment(v);
   }
   ```

**I don't recommend this way you going**
You can do everything in Fragment you dont need to pass ref to activity Please learn more about fragment